# Recomputing substring counts updating after replacing it with 'X'

Tags: python, string, replace, substring, counter

Given a string:

```
s = 'cdababef'
```

We calculate the character before and character after with:

```
def per_window(sequence, n=1):
    """
    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/42220614/610569
        >>> list(per_window([1,2,3,4], n=2))
        [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
        >>> list(per_window([1,2,3,4], n=3))
        [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
    """
    start, stop = 0, n
    seq = list(sequence)
    while stop <= len(seq):
        yield tuple(seq[start:stop])
        start += 1
        stop += 1

char_before= defaultdict(Counter)
char_after = defaultdict(Counter) 
for window in per_window(s, 3):
    char_after[window[:2]][window[2]] += 1
    char_before[window[1:]][window[0]] += 1
```

[out]:

```
>>> char_after
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {('a', 'b'): Counter({'a': 1, 'e': 1}),
             ('b', 'a'): Counter({'b': 1}),
             ('b', 'e'): Counter({'f': 1}),
             ('c', 'd'): Counter({'a': 1}),
             ('d', 'a'): Counter({'b': 1})})

>>> char_before
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {('a', 'b'): Counter({'b': 1, 'd': 1}),
             ('b', 'a'): Counter({'a': 1}),
             ('b', 'e'): Counter({'a': 1}),
             ('d', 'a'): Counter({'c': 1}),
             ('e', 'f'): Counter({'b': 1})})
```

Let's say if I replace all instances of `ab` with `x`, and I need to update the the `char_after` and `char_before` counts and the goal is to achieve **without re-counting of all the substring of `s = 'cdxxef'`** like:

```
s = 'cdxxef'
char_before2 = defaultdict(Counter)
char_after2 = defaultdict(Counter) 
for window in per_window(s, 3):
    char_after2[window[:2]][window[2]] += 1
    char_before2[window[1:]][window[0]] += 1
```

[desired outputs]:

```
>>> char_before2
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {('d', 'x'): Counter({'c': 1}),
             ('e', 'f'): Counter({'x': 1}),
             ('x', 'e'): Counter({'x': 1}),
             ('x', 'x'): Counter({'d': 1})})

>>> char_after2
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {('c', 'd'): Counter({'x': 1}),
             ('d', 'x'): Counter({'x': 1}),
             ('x', 'e'): Counter({'f': 1}),
             ('x', 'x'): Counter({'e': 1})})
```

**How can the updates of the substring be done without re-counting of all the substring but only the substrings affected by the replacements?**

---

I've tried:

```
s = 'cdababef'

char_before= defaultdict(Counter)
char_after = defaultdict(Counter) 
for window in per_window(s, 3):
    char_after[window[:2]][window[2]] += 1
    char_before[window[1:]][window[0]] += 1

source, target = ('a', 'b'), 'x'
for ch in char_before[source]:
    count_before = char_before[source][ch]
    char_before[target][ch] += count_before
    char_before[source][ch] = 0

    count_after = char_after[source][ch]
    char_after[target][ch] += count_after
    char_before[source][ch] = 0
```

But the output is not the desired one as with `char_before2` and `char_after2`:

```
>>> char_before
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'x': Counter({'b': 1, 'd': 1}),
             ('b', 'a'): Counter({'a': 1}),
             ('d', 'a'): Counter({'c': 1}),
             ('b', 'e'): Counter({'a': 1}),
             ('a', 'b'): Counter({'b': 0, 'd': 0}),
             ('e', 'f'): Counter({'b': 1})})

>>> char_after
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {'x': Counter({'b': 0, 'd': 0}),
             ('b', 'a'): Counter({'b': 1}),
             ('d', 'a'): Counter({'b': 1}),
             ('b', 'e'): Counter({'f': 1}),
             ('a', 'b'): Counter({'a': 1, 'e': 1}),
             ('c', 'd'): Counter({'a': 1})})
```

---

Comment: Can you summarize the problem?

Comment: How can the updates of the substring be done without re-counting of all the substring but only the substrings affected by the replacements?

Comment: Why is the question downvoted? Should I improve my question further?

Comment: To me, it looks like you are trying to count n-grams (or n-graphs in this case) and their immediate context.  This question makes sense if you have a very large corpus and you are doing a local replacement and want to update your counts accordingly.  This question might get more traction if you frame it in this context and throw an `nlp` tag on it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an approach that tackles this problem in three steps:

1. identify the substrings affected by the substitutions
2. remove the counts from the `char_before` and `char_after` dictionaries that are in these substrings
3. do the substitution and add the new counts to the `char_before` and `char_after` dictionaries for the affected substrings only

First let's start by defining some variables and running your initial code.

```
source, target = ('a', 'b'), 'x'
n = 3

char_before= defaultdict(Counter)
char_after = defaultdict(Counter) 
for window in per_window(s, n):
    char_after[window[:2]][window[2]] += 1
    char_before[window[1:]][window[0]] += 1
```

Now we find the spans (beginning and ending indexes) of the substrings that will be replaced (Note that we're not actually doing any replacement yet)

```
import re 

spans = [m.span() for m in re.finditer(''.join(source), s)]
```

But we know that the before and after counts of the windows that fall into one of these spans are not the only ones that will be affected by the replacement.  Any window directly preceding or following one of these spans will also be affected.  For example, in `s = 'cdababef'` if we replace `'ab'` with `'x'` the initial `'cd'` will need it's `char_after` counts updated even though no part of `'cd'` itself is replaced.

To handle this we define a function called `merge_spans` that not only merges adjacent spans (`(2,4)` and `(4,6)` becomes `(2,6)`) but also merges spans that are within `extra` spaces from each other (where `extra` is an integer defined by a keyword argument). The intuition behind this is that this will return a list of spans where the spans correspond to all the substrings who's before/after counts will be affected by the replacement.

```
def merge_spans(spans, extra = 0):
    extra = max(0,extra)
    merged = spans[:]
    if len(merged) == 1:
        return [(max(merged[0][0]-extra, 0), merged[0][-1]+extra)]
    for i in range(1, len(merged)):
        span = merged[i]
        prev = merged[i-1]
        if prev[-1]+extra >= span[0]-extra:
            merged[i] = (max(0,prev[0]-extra), span[-1]+extra)
            merged[i-1] = ()
        elif i == len(merged)-1:
            merged[i] = (max(0,span[0]-extra), span[-1]+extra)
            merged[i-1] = (max(0,prev[0]-extra), prev[-1]+extra)
        else:
            merged[i-1] = (max(0,prev[0]-extra), prev[-1]+extra)
    return list(filter(None, merged))
```

So lets create this list of spans. We set `extra` to `n-1` since `n-1` letters on either side of a replacement will be affected.

```
merged = merge_spans(spans, n-1)
```

Now we can iterate over these spans and remove the counts for the windows that are affected by the substitution. Then we can do the substitution *just within that span* and update the counts.

```
for span in merged:
    sub_s = s[span[0]:span[-1]]
    for window in per_window(sub_s, n):
        char_after[window[:2]][window[2]] -= 1
        char_before[window[1:]][window[0]] -= 1
    new_s = sub_s.replace(''.join(source), target)
    for window in per_window(new_s, n):
        char_after[window[:2]][window[2]] += 1
        char_before[window[1:]][window[0]] += 1
```

Note that the above will affect the original `char_before` and `char_after` dictionaries but you can always make copies of them first if you need to keep the original counts for some reason.

Finally, we remove any counts from the counter that are `0` or negative and completely remove any windows that contain no positive counts at all. Note that adding `Counter()` to a counter removes any elements who's value is not positive.

```
char_before2 = {k:v+Counter() for k,v in char_before.items() if any(v.values())}
char_after2 = {k:v+Counter() for k,v in char_after.items() if any(v.values())}
```

And the result:

```
>>> char_before2
{('d', 'x'): Counter({'c': 1}),
 ('e', 'f'): Counter({'x': 1}),
 ('x', 'e'): Counter({'x': 1}),
 ('x', 'x'): Counter({'d': 1})}

>>> char_after2 
{('c', 'd'): Counter({'x': 1}),
 ('d', 'x'): Counter({'x': 1}),
 ('x', 'e'): Counter({'f': 1}),
 ('x', 'x'): Counter({'e': 1})}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I found a problem: For `s='cdabef'` I get `('a', 'b')` in the keys of `char_before2`, which should not be there.
Additionally the performance of your approach is quite bad (although the question does not state whether this is actually about performance): You still have to do the actual counting in step 2 and 3. In fact you do it twice.
I tested this with `timeit`, and at least for the example input the merging takes about 5 times as long as simply recalculating.

Comment: one more remark about performance: for quite long strings `s` and a small number of replacements the merge approach is indeed faster.

Comment: Thank you @Feodoran for pointing out that bug. The function wasn't properly handling cases where only one substitution was found.  I have edited my answer so the current function should cover this case.

Comment: As to the performance issue, yes this way will be slower if a significant portion of the input string is covered by the spans in merge.  In fact, with the example string `s = 'cdababef'` the spans in `merged` cover the **whole string**!. However, as you pointed out, this is faster for long strings with few substitutions which I assume is more the situation that @alvas intended it be used for (since otherwise you might as well just substitute and recount)

Answer (score 3):

Not really an answer, but this is too long for a comment:

This seems to be a quite complex problem. I am not sure whether it is really worth doing it, or if it is even possible.

In your suggested code you did not consider certain cases. For example you did not account for possible double replacements (`'ab'` occurs twice in `s`). That's why you get the `'x'` key but not `('x', 'x')`. Also you did not consider your window being only half over the replaced sequence, which is why you are missing for example the key `('d', 'x')`.

Another thing: Assume we start with `s='cdababaef'`, then we would have `char_after[('a','b')]['a']=2` and for the replaced string we need `char_after[('x','x')]['a']=1`.

For `s='cdabaabaef'` we would also get `char_after[('a','b')]['a']=2`, however in the replaced string it will be `char_after[('x','x')]['a']=2`.

What I am trying to say is: **How do we know, whether the character we counted after `source` (`'ab'` in our example) is going to be replaced as well or not?** For this information we would need to consult `s` in our algorithm (unless `char_before` and `char_after` would be unique for their input `s`, but this seems to be another complex question.)

It seems to me that it would be much easier to simply go with recounting. If you can afford to run it for the original sequence, you can probably afford to run it for the replaced sequence again. Otherwise this question becomes more of a code-optimization question, which you maybe can ask again in [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

But maybe somebody else has a clever idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the most obvious way to do this is just to search linearly through your string looking for occurrences of the source sequence. As you go, you copy substrings that do not match the source string into the new string. When you do find a match to the source string, you copy the target sequence (rather than the source sequence) into the new string. You then scan through the sequence around the replacement to determine which substrings have before/after counts affected by the replacement and update the counts. You save the position of the target insertion, and, after you're done making the replacement, come back and add in the new counts resulting from the substitutions.

If I understand bunji's answer correctly, then this is conceptually identical to what he/she did. It's not pretty, but here is another implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter
import re
from copy import deepcopy

def chars_before_after(s, bin_size):
    def per_window(sequence, n=1):
        """
        From http://stackoverflow.com/q/42220614/610569
            >>> list(per_window([1,2,3,4], n=2))
            [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
            >>> list(per_window([1,2,3,4], n=3))
            [(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
        """
        start, stop = 0, n
        seq = list(sequence)
        while stop <= len(seq):
            yield tuple(seq[start:stop])
            start += 1
            stop += 1

    char_before= defaultdict(Counter)
    char_after = defaultdict(Counter)
    for window in per_window(s, bin_size+1):
        char_after[window[:bin_size]][window[-1]] += 1
        char_before[window[1:]][window[0]] += 1

    return char_before, char_after

def replace_chars_recount(s, source, target, char_before, char_after, verbose=False):

    if verbose:
        print('s=' + s + ', source=' + source, 'target=' + target)

        print('char_before')
        for char_counter in char_before.items():
            print(char_counter)

        print('\nchar_after')
        for char_counter in char_after.items():
            print(char_counter)

    char_before = deepcopy(char_before)
    char_after = deepcopy(char_after)
    replaced_s = ''
    source_len = len(source)
    source_start = 0
    source_stop = source_len
    target_pos = []
    target_len = len(target)
    last_replacement = 0

    while source_start < len(s):
        if verbose: print('start_index=' + str(source_start))

        if s[source_start:source_stop] == source:
            replaced_s += target

            before_start = max(source_start-source_len+last_replacement,0)
            before_end = before_start+source_len
            while before_start < source_stop and before_end < len(s):
                before_chars = tuple(s[before_start:before_end])
                if verbose: print('Removing "'+ s[before_end] +'" from after "' + s[before_start:before_end] + '".')
                char_after[before_chars][s[before_end]] -= 1
                before_start += 1
                before_end += 1

            after_end = min(len(s), source_stop+source_len)
            after_start = after_end-source_len
            while after_end > source_start+last_replacement and after_start>0:
                after_chars = tuple(s[after_start:after_end])
                if verbose: print('Removing "' + s[after_start-1] + '" from before "' + s[after_start:after_end] + '".')
                char_before[after_chars][s[after_start-1]] -= 1
                after_start -= 1
                after_end -= 1

            target_pos.append(len(replaced_s) - target_len)
            source_start += source_len
            source_stop += source_len
            last_replacement = source_len

        else:
            replaced_s += s[source_start]
            source_start += 1
            source_stop += 1
            last_replacement = max(0, last_replacement-1)

    last_target = 0-target_len
    for target in target_pos:
        if verbose: print('target_pos=' + str(target))
        before_target_start = max(target-source_len, last_target+target_len, 0)
        before_target_end = before_target_start+source_len
        while before_target_start <= target+target_len-1 and before_target_end < len(replaced_s):
            before_chars = tuple(replaced_s[before_target_start:before_target_end])
            if verbose: print('Adding "' + replaced_s[before_target_end] + '" to after "' + replaced_s[before_target_start:before_target_end] + '".')
            char_after[before_chars][replaced_s[before_target_end]] += 1
            before_target_start += 1
            before_target_end += 1

        after_end = min(len(replaced_s), target + target_len+ source_len)
        after_start = after_end - source_len
        while after_end > max(target, last_target+source_len+target_len) and after_start>0:
            after_chars = tuple(replaced_s[after_start:after_end])
            if verbose: print('Adding "' + replaced_s[after_start - 1] + '" to before "' + replaced_s[after_start:after_end] + '".')
            char_before[after_chars][replaced_s[after_start - 1]] += 1
            after_start -= 1
            after_end -= 1

        last_target=target

    char_before = {k:v+Counter() for k,v in char_before.items() if any(v.values())}
    char_after = {k:v+Counter() for k,v in char_after.items() if any(v.values())}

    if verbose:
        print('replaced_s=' + replaced_s)
        print('char_before')
        for char_counter in char_before.items():
            print(char_counter)

        print('\nchar_after')
        for char_counter in char_after.items():
            print(char_counter)

    return replaced_s, char_before, char_after


def test_replace_chars_recount(s, source, target, verbose=False):
    char_before, char_after = chars_before_after(s, len(source))
    replaced_s, char_before, char_after = replace_chars_recount(s, source, target, char_before, char_after, verbose)
    correct_replaced = re.sub(source, target, s)
    correct_before, correct_after = chars_before_after(replaced_s, len(source))
    correct_answer = correct_replaced==replaced_s and correct_before==char_before and correct_after==char_after

    print('{:>20} {:<20} {:<10} {:<10} {:<5}'.format(s, replaced_s, source, target, str(correct_answer)))

test_cases = [{'s': 'cdababef', 'source': 'ab', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'cdabqabef', 'source': 'ab', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'cdabgabgef', 'source': 'abg', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'cdabgqabgef', 'source': 'abg', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'cdababef', 'source': 'ab', 'target': 'xy'},
              {'s': 'cdababef', 'source': 'ab', 'target': 'xyz'},
              {'s': 'cdababef', 'source': 'a', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'cdababef', 'source': 'a', 'target': 'xyz'},
              {'s': 'ababef', 'source': 'ab', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'cdabab', 'source': 'ab', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'cdababef', 'source': 'xy', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'cdababef', 'source': 'ab', 'target': ''},
              {'s': 'cdabcdabcdef', 'source': 'abcd', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'cdabcdeabcdeabcdeef', 'source': 'abcde', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'cdababef', 'source': 'a', 'target': 'abcd'},
              {'s': 'aaaaa', 'source': 'a', 'target': 'x'},
              {'s': 'aaaaa', 'source': 'a', 'target': 'xy'},
              {'s': '', 'source': '', 'target': ''}]

print('{:>20} {:<20} {:<10} {:<10} {:<5}'.format('Input String', 'Output String', 'Source', 'Target', 'Correct Result?'))

for test_case in test_cases:
    test_replace_chars_recount(test_case['s'], test_case['source'], test_case['target'])
```

The output is:

```
    Input String Output String        Source     Target     Correct Result?
            cdababef cdxxef               ab         x          True 
           cdabqabef cdxqxef              ab         x          True 
          cdabgabgef cdxxef               abg        x          True 
         cdabgqabgef cdxqxef              abg        x          True 
            cdababef cdxyxyef             ab         xy         True 
            cdababef cdxyzxyzef           ab         xyz        True 
            cdababef cdxbxbef             a          x          True 
            cdababef cdxyzbxyzbef         a          xyz        True 
              ababef xxef                 ab         x          True 
              cdabab cdxx                 ab         x          True 
            cdababef cdababef             xy         x          True 
            cdababef cdef                 ab                    True 
        cdabcdabcdef cdxxef               abcd       x          True 
 cdabcdeabcdeabcdeef cdxxxef              abcde      x          True 
            cdababef cdabcdbabcdbef       a          abcd       True 
               aaaaa xxxxx                a          x          True 
               aaaaa xyxyxyxyxy           a          xy         True 
                                                                True
```

So this approach works regardless of source/target length. The one limitation in the current implementation is that the source length must be the same as the bin size for the before/after character counting. However, you could change this so it's more flexible.